# Sending nearby taps to a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiresponder

I have a `UICollectionView` where cells are text sized so the whole thing may end up being only about 13 or 30pt tall, depending.  Needless to say, the cells are really hard to tap.

[image]

To solve this problem, I'm trying to send nearby tap events into the collection view with `hitTest:withEvent:` and `pointInside:withEvent:`.

```
CGPoint ShiftNearbyPointInside(CGPoint point, CGRect bounds, CGFloat radius) {
    if (point.y < 0 && point.y > -radius) {
        point.y = 1;
    }

    if (point.y > CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) && point.y < CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) + radius) {
        point.y = CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - 1;
    }

    return point;
}

@implementation MyCollectionView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return [super hitTest:ShiftNearbyPointInside(point, self.bounds, self.enlargedTapRadius) withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return [super pointInside:ShiftNearbyPointInside(point, self.bounds, self.enlargedTapRadius) withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

This works for highlighting.  If I touch within `enlargedTapRadius` points from the top or bottom of the collection view, the cell becomes highlighted, but when I release, the delegate is never called.  I'm using a similar technique for a `UIButton` and it works well.  Is there something else needed to get the touch up event to sink in?